# Are there any UEFA regulations for longer added time in football?

Tags: rules, football

Recently we can see matches getting longer and longer. It started with Qatar and FIFA asking referees to prolong added time as much as possible, if there were any delays. Apparently more than 9 hours were added with extra time in all matches, as calculated e.g. [here](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/12/5/why-has-there-been-so-much-stoppage-time-at-the-2022-world-cup).

Now we have very long matches in La Liga and Premier League - e.g. Getafe vs Barcelona - this season.

I'm wondering if anything like that applies to European leagues such as Champions League. I've seen articles about UEFA representatives rejecting/disliking the idea, e.g. [this one](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2023/aug/30/uefa-to-avoid-inflated-added-time-in-champions-league). Zvonimir Boban said:

> I can say that it’s absolutely absurd myself,

Yet I could see some very long added times even in qualifiers of all the leagues. E.g. Viktoria Plzen - Drita had ~25 minutes of added time in 2nd half alone.

Any idea if any official regulations were established regarding this?

Some other references:

- [IFAB encourages World Cup-style extended stoppage time to combat time wasting](https://www.insidethegames.biz/articles/1134406/ifab-stoppage-time)

> The International Football Association Board (IFAB) has encouraged referees to follow the approach taken at last year's FIFA World Cup in Qatar and introduce extended periods of stoppage time to combat time wasting.

- [Premier League new rule changes for 2023/24 season: Top-flight chiefs crackdown on dissent and time-wasting](https://talksport.com/football/1517171/premier-league-rule-changes-2023-24-season-stoppage-time-fouls/)

> The Premier League are taking their cue from the 2022 World Cup after stats showed the ball was only in play around 55 minutes on average in top-flight games last term.
>
> Referees will now be obliged to specifically time interruptions before restarts after a goal, a substitution, injury, or set-piece.

Comment: What data exists to suggest any subjective impression of longer added time is actually occurring, instead of remaining unchanged within a reasonable statistical expectation?

Comment: I don't need to collect any data to ask if any new regulations were added and one stat for world cup was mentioned. Even without stats it's clear that it's getting longer and it's a common topic nowadays, if even UEFA representatives are discussing it. What a nonsense reason to downvote.

Comment: I've witnessed it in Germany too and not just in the Bundesliga. But as far as my imagination goes the UEFA doesn't set the rules for domestic leagues. If they choose to do that it's their own rule book.